# Uploading a file into webApp using python selenium when after clicking a button, file selection window comes up

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have checked all the solution provided in other similar question, but nothing works for my scenario. I have a button with ID `uploadFileButton`, now when I try the provided solution of providing the file path by sending keys to the element, nothing happens. And when I try to use solution which implies javascript execution with following code:

```
driver.execute_script(r"document.getElementById('uploadFileButton').value='path\to\file'")
```

I was getting the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

even when I am able to get the element with this ID while trying outside the javascript.
The above exception occurs for firefox 58.0 and above browser. Because above 58 version, they have turned on WebDriver specific interactability checks which needs to be off to be intractable with the element and then sending keys to the input node would work fine. 
How to make this check off or how to overcome this issue?
Any other solution? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide the link to the site?

Comment: can you share the html for upload button?

Comment: what is the type of this button uploadFileButton?

Comment: @Stack, unfortunately, I can not share the site link :(

Comment: @Murthi, it is exceeding the character limit of the comment

Comment: @cruisepandey, the type is button only, not input

Comment: @ShubhamShrivastava : Can you share the html ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, I would but it is exceeding the character limit of the comment.

Comment: Also there is one input node where when I send keys it is working fine BUT for Linux only, for windows I am getting `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="fileInput" otherAttrbs> is not reachable by keyboard` exception. Do I have to use AutoIt for windows?

Comment: The above exception occurs for firefox 58.0 and above browser. Because above 58 version,  they have turned on WebDriver specific interactability checks which needs to be off to be intractable with the element and then sending keys to the input node would work fine.

Comment: @ShubhamShrivastava : Try to edit the question with the relevant content , no need to add it in comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs for firefox 58.0 and above browsers. Because above 58 version,  they have turned on WebDriver specific interactability checks which need to be off to be intractable with the element and then sending keys to the input node would work fine.
Hope it was helpful. :)

Comment: Now the question is: How to make this check off?